# Vb.net dims in buttons turning to 0

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have this snippet from my code

```
Private Sub BtnOne_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles BtnOne.Click
    Dim ownerNum As Integer 'sets variable
    ownerNum = Ownerfnc(Indicatorbtn, ownerNum) 'gives variable a number
End Sub

Function cntOwner(ByRef indicator As Object, ByRef old As Integer) As Integer
    If indicator.FillColor = Color.Transparent Then
       indicator.FillColor = Color.green
        Return player
    Else
        Return old
    End If

End Function
```

when i click the button it sets the variable to the correct number but if i click it again it sets it back to 0 is there a way to stop it from doing it?
Thanks

Comment: can you please post your complete code? use `` when inserting code

Comment: Please add `Options Strict On` to the top of your code or set in the projects settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, needed to explain a bit more that i have 42 different variables that where in 42 different button clicks.

The answer was to just put static instead of dim and that worked fine for anyone that was looking for a solution like this

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable globally (outside procedure) to persist it's value.

At the moment, your variable declared locally within procedure. That way it will be recreated -hence get reset to default value- every time the procedure called. For reference, read this : [MSDN - Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you should declare your variable outside the events of button click. every time you you click the button the value of ownerNum is reseting. try dis code

`Dim ownerNum As Integer 'sets variable`

`Private Sub BtnOne_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles BtnOne.Click
    'now every time you click the ownerNum is not reseting.
    ownerNum = Ownerfnc(Indicatorbtn, ownerNum) 'gives variable a number
End Sub`

`Function cntOwner(ByRef indicator As Object, ByRef old As Integer) As Integer
    If indicator.FillColor = Color.Transparent Then
       indicator.FillColor = Color.green
        Return player
    Else
        Return old
    End If`

`End Function`